# C# itextSharp - How to show Bookmark by Default

Tags: c#, pdf

I have used iTextSharp library to create bookmark for each pdf in a directory with code below.

Below code could create bookmark in each PDF successfully but cannot show bookmark as initial view by default when open the pdf.

Anyone has the idea what's wrong with my code?

```
public static void createBookmark(string sourcefilepart)
    {
        try
        {
            #region Try

            var pdfList = new DirectoryInfo(sourcefilepart).GetFiles("*.pdf");
            int pdfCount = pdfList.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < pdfCount; i++)
            {
                string sourceFileName = pdfList[i].Name.Substring(0 , pdfList[i].Name.Length - 4);
                string newFileName = sourceFileName + "_new.pdf";
                string newFilePathName = sourcefilepart + newFileName;

                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfList[i].FullName);
                int totalPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                Document pdfDoc = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFilePathName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //get PdfWriter object
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);
                    writer.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines;

                    PdfCopy pdfCopyDoc = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, fs);
                    pdfDoc.Open();

                    List<Dictionary<String, Object>> bookmarks = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();

                    for (int j = 1; j <= totalPages; j++)
                    {
                        PdfImportedPage ip = pdfCopyDoc.GetImportedPage(reader, totalPages);

                        if (j == totalPages)
                        {
                            Dictionary<String, Object> ht = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                            ht.Add("Title", sourceFileName);
                            bookmarks.Add(ht);
                        }

                        pdfCopyDoc.AddPage(ip);
                    }

                    pdfCopyDoc.Outlines = bookmarks;

                    pdfDoc.Close();
                }

                reader.Close();

                PdfReader newPdfReader = new PdfReader(newFilePathName);
                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(newPdfReader, new FileStream(Path.Combine(sourcefilepart, sourceFileName + "_bookmark.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
                //Show Bookmark
                stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.PAGEMODE, PdfName.USEOUTLINES);
                stamper.Close();
                newPdfReader.Close();
            }
            #endregion Try
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I revise with refercing "BookmarkedTimeTable.java" (http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7#297-bookmarkedtimetable.java)

Answer (score 1):

I revise as below which looks fine now.

```
    public static void createBookmark(string sourcefilepart)
    {
        try
        {
            #region Try

            var pdfList = new DirectoryInfo(sourcefilepart).GetFiles("*.pdf");
            int pdfCount = pdfList.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < pdfCount; i++)
            {

                List<Dictionary<String, Object>> bookmarks = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();
                Dictionary<String, Object> ht = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

                //Get Existing PDF doc name
                string sourceFileName = pdfList[i].Name.Substring(0, pdfList[i].Name.Length - 4);

                //Define New PDF doc name
                string newFileName = sourceFileName + "_new.pdf";
                string newFilePathName = sourcefilepart + newFileName;

                //Create Bookmark List                  
                ht.Add("Title", sourceFileName);
                bookmarks.Add(ht);

                //Create a reder for PDF doc
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfList[i].FullName);
                // Create a stamper
                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFilePathName, FileMode.Create));
                //Show Bookmark
                stamper.Outlines = bookmarks;
                stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.PAGEMODE, PdfName.USEOUTLINES);
                stamper.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
            #endregion Try
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If this is the answer to your question. Please mark it as answered.